# Openrowset using Execute As

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Using SQL Server 2014

I am pulling data in from an Excel file using OpenRowSet.

I have a folder on a separate server that I have given my own windows account full permission to and added in the file that I want to import.

When running the below code

```
Alter procedure [dbo].[usp_e_import]

WITH EXECUTE AS 'Domain\user'

as

delete from ETable

insert into ETable
select * from openrowset('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=\\server\sharedfolder\upload\Spreadsheet.xlsx;HDR=YES;IMEX=1', 'SELECT * FROM [DataT$]')
```

I get the error

```
Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted.
```

My own SQL account has Admin Privileges on the SQL server.

Just a further note, if I log in to SQL Server with my own credentials and run the code with the `WITH EXECUTE` command set to me it fails, which does not make sense as I am technically only passing the same credentials twice.

If I comment out `WITH EXECUTE` everything works as it should.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolve this issue?

Comment: May I ask why you dont do in SSIS? Something like this I wouldnt do in t-sql

Comment: hi mvisser, unfortunately there is no set time when a file will be added to this location and a user once to be able to run the process as and when they feel like it.

Comment: When using `EXECUTE AS`, you tell SQL Server to change the execution context to another SQL Server login or database user. Unfortunately (for your requirement), this is indeed just another "SQL Server user" but (although it might have the same name) not another Windows user that is authenticated by your operating system and that might have access to the file. So, this kind of impersonation takes place at the SQL Server level only, I don't think that you will be able to tell SQL Server to change the context at the OS level.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Bulk Insert

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[usp_e_import]

AS

DELETE TableName

BULK INSERT TableName
FROM '\\server\folder\Book1.csv'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 1,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    TABLOCK
)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply, I am afraid that the file file that I am importing is an xlsx file, when using your code and substituting your path and table for my own I am getting the following errors :- "Bulk load data conversion error (trucation) for row 1, column 1 (Alert Type) & Bulk load data conversion error (trucation) for row 1, column 1 (E ID)"  I am not sure if this is an issue as the code was originally meant for a CSV file or the fact that the data within the file is not the best due to having to export from a system I have no control over the underlying data.